# Simple date format reading month incorrectly

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am working with converting Date Strings to Epoch times then back again, but it seems like when I convert to Epoch the month is ignored when I parse the date String

```
String timeString = "15 Aug 2005 13:07:58.035";
Date dateTime = null;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("DD MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.US);
try {
    dateTime = sdf.parse(timeString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
long convert = dateTime.getTime();
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(convert);
Date epochToString = new Date(convert);
System.out.println(epochToString.toString());
```

Here is the output

```
15 Aug 2005 13:07:58.035
1105812478000
Sat Jan 15 13:07:58 EST 2005
```

When I calculated the epoch time by hand the date was indeed Jan 15 2005, so for some reason the MMM value is being ignored in my format.

Edit:
I should also note that I changed the format token to MM and tried a numerical representation in the string instead, but had the same exact results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `DD` means day in year. You want `dd` for day in month. See [SimpleDateFormat Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

I suggest you use `HH` for 24 hour time.

Comment: This isn't correct, I am using mm for minutes in the second half of my string, and the javadoc does actually say MMM is the token for months, thanks though.

Comment: @pianoisland you are right, fixed my answer.